# Xampp mysql Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

when I starting mysql, giving the following error:

```
17:43:13  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
17:43:13  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:43:13  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:43:13  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:43:13  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:43:13  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
17:43:13  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

then, I check the mysql_error.log:

```
    2017-05-03 17:39:39 202c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in        future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1600674 in         the ib_logfiles!
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    170503 17:39:39 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    170503 17:39:40 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1600674
    170503 17:39:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    170503 17:39:40 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

finally, I moved xampp/mysql/backup files into xampp/mysql/data and run mysql again.Then, it worked!But I don't know why.What led to this problem.

Hope someone doubts for me！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running XAMPP as an administrator, shutting down MySQL can cause corruption which means you have to repair or delete your tables. This can easily be avoided by running XAMPP as administrator.

Comment: Maybe you are right, the problem is really on the table.Thank you for your answer！

Answer (score 6):

I searched on google and tried everything like port changing, delete files, reinstall xampp, copy and paste backup files to mysql/data folder but nothing worked.

I found the best solution to this problem.

**Solution:**

1. go to xampp/mysql/data and take a backup of this folder
2. delete all selected files in the below image
   [image]
3. Copy selected files in below image from xampp/mysql/backup and paste it to xampp/mysql/data folder
   [image]
4. Now restart your xampp server and it will run like before. no need to delete your database or reinstall your xampp server

Comment: It deletes all databases. Never do that.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **Services** on **XAMPP Control Panel**
- Look for the service **MySQL80**, right click on this service and click *Stop*
- Get back to **XAMPP Control Panel** and *start* MySQL

Comment: MySQL80 is not available in services. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

Open Services on XAMPP Control Panel
Look for the Services > MySQL80,
right click on this Services and click Stop
Get back to XAMPP Control Panel and start MySQL

thanks to @Shahjahan

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).